# indexing multiple minimum values from a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a set of coordinates in the below data structure.
How do I find the indices for the K minimal X value points?
e.g. for the below data with `k=3`, the output should be something like `[5,4,3]`

```
array([[[463, 445]],
       [[461, 447]],
       [[461, 448]],
       [[ 42,   2]],
       [[ 41,   1]],
       [[ 40, 100]]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is not in `nx2` shape, reshape it first and use `argsort` to get the sorted indices and index first `k`

```
x = np.array(
    [[[463, 445]],
     [[461, 447]],
     [[461, 448]],
     [[ 42,   2]],
     [[ 41,   1]],
     [[ 40, 100]]])

k = 3
print (np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k][:,0])
```

Ouput:

```
[5 4 3]
```

- `x.reshape(-1,2)` : Reshape into `n X 2`
- `np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)` : Sort at columns; so both `x's` and `y's` are sorted independently
- `np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k]`: Get the top k idx
- `np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k][:,0]`: Get the idx of x's

To do the same on `y's` are you need to do is index the idx `of y`s` ie.

```
print (np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k][:,1])
```

Output:

```
array([5, 4, 3])
```

Comment: Thank you. How is this achieved elegantly for the y axis?
axis=0 seems to infer the first column however axis=1 doesn't do the trick the second. what am I missing?

Comment: `use np.argsort(x.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k][:,1]` explained the code